# Intel XDK / Cordova: 'ContactFindOptions' is not defined

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, mobile, intel-xdk

Estou tentando simular uma listagem de contatos com o Intel XDK. Porém não está funcionando, aparecendo o erro:

> ContactFindOptions' is not defined

Instalei o *plugin* Contacts do Cordova no Projeto, mas o problema persiste, segue imagens:

-- Plugins:
[image: SS]

-- Instância do objeto e mensagem de erro:
[image: SS]

Desta forma a aplicação não está funcionando, obviamente.

Será que tem alguma coisa haver com aquelas permissões READ_CONTACT e as outras?

Comment: O intel XDK já vem com uma ferramenta para acessar a agenda. Não conseguiu usá-lo?

Comment: Estou acompanhando um tutorial e nele precisava instalar o plugin Contacts do Cordova. Então, ainda sou um pouco leigo, não sei sobre esta ferramenta da qual fala. Como usá-la?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui nesse link: http://qnimate.com/accessing-user-phone-contacts-using-intel-xdk/. Aproveita e já visita as outras coisas que o tutorial deste indiano aborda.